# Using function argument (parameter) in a constant context in Go

Tags: go, constants

Is it somehow possible to use a function's argument in a constant context?
For example

```golang
func example(size int) {
  one := [size]int{}  // Error: non-constant array bound 'size' 
  const two = size    // Error: const initializer 'size' is not a constant
}
```

Is `size` not *effectively constant* in these cases? If not, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible in Go. Go constants are compile-time constructs, while parameter values only exist at runtime.

[Spec: Constant expressions:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions)

> Constant expressions may contain only [constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) operands and are evaluated at compile time.

Recommended reading: [The Go Blog: Constants](https://blog.golang.org/constants)